# How to format a Double from 1234567 to 1 234.567 in a safe manner

Tags: java, formatting

All in the title..,  I'm looking for a safe way to format all Double in this manner, some other examples:

```
1000 ==> 1.000

1500 ==> 1.500

22000 ==> 22.000

1555005 ==> 1 555.005
```

I have looked in [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/text/DecimalFormat.html)  but not helped...

there is a safe way to do that ? THX in advance

Comment: Is the dot a thousands separator or a decimal sign?

Comment: I work with a French customer.. yes its a dot of thousands(I assume)..

Comment: so you want spaces for separators from 1000000 up, but a dot for 1000, correct?

Comment: check this link it will answer your question http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to print your input number divided by a thousand, using a decimal dot and space as thousand separator. The safe way is to first convert to `BigDecimal`, scale by 10<sup>-3</sup>, then print it using `DecimalFormat`.

```
final DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#,###.000");
final DecimalFormatSymbols s = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
s.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
s.setDecimalSeparator('.');
f.setDecimalFormatSymbols(s);
final double input = 1_555_005;
final BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(input).scaleByPowerOfTen(-3);
System.out.println(f.format(x));
```

prints

```
1 555.005
```

Note that setting grouping/decimal separators explicitly like here is **not** the orthodox way to do this: normally you would let the Locale setting dictate the number format.

Answer (score 2):

this is taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html)

```
static public void displayNumber(Locale currentLocale) {

    Integer quantity = new Integer(123456);
    Double amount = new Double(345987.246);
    NumberFormat numberFormatter;
    String quantityOut;
    String amountOut;

    numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(currentLocale);
    quantityOut = numberFormatter.format(quantity);
    amountOut = numberFormatter.format(amount);
    System.out.println(quantityOut + "   " + currentLocale.toString());
    System.out.println(amountOut + "   " + currentLocale.toString());
}
```

This example prints the following; it shows how the format of the same number varies with Locale:

```
123 456   fr_FR
345 987,246   fr_FR
123.456   de_DE
345.987,246   de_DE
123,456   en_US
345,987.246   en_US
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use the java formatting API. There is a nice tutorial on number formatting at  - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html.

You can get a locale based formatter for French and format:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(loc);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
df.applyPattern(pattern);
String output = df.format(value);
System.out.println(pattern + " " + output + " " + loc.toString());
```

For French the output will be something like this:

```
###,###.###      123 456,789     fr_FR
```